# Do Agent systems developed in Jade must be distributed?

Tags: java, jena, agent, agents-jade

I am hoping to build a system where Agents take a search query from a mobile application and search in a semantically stored information and give a result set. I am planning to built the middle ware of the system with jade Agent framework and semantic layer with jena. But according to my knowledge my system is not distributed. Is it worth while to use Agents or not?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it worth while to use Agents or not?

No, it's not.

Using agents is not about building a distributed system, it's about whether you want to architect your system around units of *autonomous behaviour*, with their own goals, strategies and beliefs. There's nothing in your description that says that you would need that extra complexity to solve your users needs.

My advice: don't focus on *how* you're going to build your system, focus on *what your users need*. Then make the simplest technology choices that you can in order to meet those needs. As you build your application, your understanding of your users needs will change, and your application will have to change with it. The more complexity you build in from the get go, the harder it will be to be agile in responding to your changing understanding of the problem.